# I would like to show a line bar in chart.js with data automatically fetched from mockapi

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, chart.js

I struggle with my second chart in chart.js and I can't find answer for my question...I have an array with dates and amounts. I would like to put these values from array automatically to chart. I've tried simple way but it doesn't work... 
Months is an array with dates on which amount was received, 
myData is an array with amounts of donations. 
That's the code:

```
let DonationChart2 = new Chart(myChart2, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: [Months],
        datasets: [{
            data: [myData]

        }]
    },
})
```

The months are visible but unfortunately not as separate labels - just in 1 column... I would like to see them as bottom description under each amount... The donation amount is visible only when I write myData[here the position in array], otherwise is empty....I assume I assigned wrong these values..probably somehow I should to indicate to show each value as separate ? but I don't know how...It's my first day with chart.js...hence these problems...

Comment: can you give an example of your data set `myData` and `Months`?

Comment: of course :)   MyData:   Array(14)
0: "60"
1: "80"
2: "5"
3: "100"
4: "60"
5: "20"
6: "50"
7: "100"
8: "50"
9: "100"
10: "2000"
11: "8000"
12: "234"
13: "22"

Comment: 0: "Mon Dec 17 2018 16:36:04 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)"
1: "Mon Dec 17 2018 17:36:34 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)"
2: "Thu Dec 20 2018 09:34:18 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)"
3: "Thu Dec 20 2018 09:37:16 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)"
4: "Thu Dec 20 2018 12:41:51 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)"
5: "Thu Dec 20 2018 13:52:15 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)"
6: "Thu Dec 20 2018 12:46:48 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)"
7: "Thu Dec 20 2018 16:26:59 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)"

Comment: 8: "Tue Dec 25 2018 13:47:43 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)"
9: "Thu Dec 27 2018 14:40:29 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)"
10: "Fri Jan 04 2019 12:46:51 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)"
11: "Fri Jan 04 2019 12:52:25 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)"
12: "Tue Jan 08 2019 15:32:29 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)"
13: "Tue Jan 08 2019 19:04:02 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)"

Comment: I actually have to shortcut this data to limit to day month and year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your `Months` and `myData` vars you were wrapping them in another array (the `[]` around the variable name). Due to that, the chart only saw 1 label and 1 data point, which is not what you want.

I removed the outer `[]` so that only your arrays are set as the label and data on the configuration.

One more thing I anticipated is that you would deal with long label names (like `Mon Dec 17 2018 16:36:04 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)`) which wouldn't look good on your graph.

To fix that I shortened the date by creating a new date obj and using [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) on it. I also read that if a label is represented as an array instead of a single string then each part would be on a new line.

This is where [.split(",")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) can help. `toLocaleString()` returns, for example, the string `"12/20/2018, 12:00:00 PM"` so the split function would split that string wherever there is a comma and push the result to an array. The resulting array will have index 0 as `12/20/2018` and index 1 as `12:00:00 PM` so each would be on its own line in the graph.

```js
const myData = ["60", "80", "5", "100", "60"];
const months = ["Mon Dec 17 2018 16:36:04 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)", "Mon Dec 17 2018 17:36:34 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)", "Thu Dec 20 2018 09:34:18 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)", "Thu Dec 20 2018 09:37:16 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)", "Thu Dec 20 2018 12:41:51 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)"];

let newMonths = months.map(function(date){
  return new Date(date).toLocaleString().split(",");
});

let myChart2 = document.getElementById("myChart2").getContext('2d');
let DonationChart2 = new Chart(myChart2, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: newMonths,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Amount',
      data: myData
    }]
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart2" width="1000" height="900"></canvas>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help :) I didn't know this useful method - tolocaleString() and I was trying do it all around :D It's also good lesson for me with [ ]. I thought (due to tutorials I've watched about chart.js) that's something mandatory for chart.js... thank you very much i appreciate your help :)

Comment: actually when i think of it it was really silly obviously it was an array - []..I just relied too much on tutorial and didn't think what I'm doing I assume :/